# Is the versions 12 vs 14 Object Library causing Excel VBA “Code execution has been halted”?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel 2007 running the 12 Object Library.  The macros run fine when opening the workbook in Excel 2007.  However, there is a “Code execution has been halted” message whenever the macros are run in Excel 2010 (the actual break occurs during a ListObjects.Unlink method).  I  F8 through the breaks but it keeps stopping at each ListObjects.Unlink.

I checked the references on both versions of VBE. The Excel 2007 runs the Object Library Version 12 and the Excel 2010 runs Version 14. There doesn’t seem to be an issue running any other code. Any ideas of what is happening?

Another post on this site recommended clicking debug and pressing [Ctrl+Break] twice to continue.  Is there another work around?

Thanks